# #include <Python.h> no such file or directory for windows 10 fix

Tags: python, c, windows, header

I am trying to build an extension in C for python 3 and I am using Windows. This might be a duplicate question but all the answers for the other question were for linux and I can run sudo on windows.
How do I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer.
You must first search in your python directory for the 'include' folder, for example: "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include", this is where mine is located and then search for Python.h and like that, you have the header.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is just the *sudo*-thing, you can have an admin-Terminal easily.
Open your start menu, search for PowerShell, right click -> run as admin
With Powershell you can use most important UNIX-commands.

If your IDE or Text Editor does not find a header file like  the reason most likely is that this cpp-Header is either not installed or the Path to  is not defined. Look for sth like "include-path" in your IDE´s Settings.

Comment: sudo does not work on windows, regardless if I use powershell or not

Comment: I am using CodeBlocks and I searched for something like include-path, like you said but I can't find anything

Comment: The point is that if you right click -> "run as admin" your shell on Windows, it *has the same effect* as using `sudo` on Linux. Or close enough, anyway.

Comment: sudo just gives you administrator rights for that single command. if you have your shell started as an admin you have all rights you can get.

Answer (score 0):

You need add the includes and libs, example of compilation on Windows using clang (shared = dll)

```
clang -shared pythontest.c -Ofast -o test.dll -I"C:\Python312\include" -l"C:\Python312\libs\python312.lib"
```

You can rename dll to pyc and use:

```
import test
```